# Connecting to SQL from Bamboo still throws error Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, bamboo

I am attempting to connect my Bamboo instance to SQL Server, but I am unable to do so because of the error Login failed for user 'Bamboo'. Investigation into the log files shown in the location

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
```

throws an error that I should not be getting at this stage of my attempted login. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. Currently able to login using same SQL Server credentials to access the database, just not via Bamboo.

The reason why this should not happen is because my server is already set up to do so, and I will list all of the steps that I have taken to prevent this error.  In my localhost SQLEXPRESS server I have checked SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode. Once I restarted SQL Server, this worked as I was able to log in with the credentials that I added to a user called `Bamboo`.

The user I added is mapped to the database called `BambooDatabase` as a `db_owner`. The number of concurrent users is unlimited and I have tried disconnecting from SQL Server just to check if that was a problem, but still no difference.  I added 2 more users with connect access and mapped to `BambooDatabase`.

I have went to the SQL Sever Configuration Manager and enabled TCP/IP and made sure that the IP addresses was pointing to 1433. And then configured my firewall to all access to 1433 as well. The fact that my error logs for SQL Server are appearing makes this seem that everything should be fine here. So with tested 3 users on SQL credentials everyone logged in successfully and all have the relevant permissions needed. All three gave the same error when trying to connect from Bamboo.

I am trying to connect to Bamboo like this:

1. Direct JDBC connection.
2. Driver class name: net.source.jtds.jdbc.Driver
3. Database URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=BambooDatabase
4. User name: Bamboo
5. Password: SQL Server password
6. Checked overwrite existing data

Then once I click continue the log in error throws. Have I missed something here, I cannot see what I could do differently, I have tried to connect to SQL Server from Bamboo several different ways but have had no success. I am using SQL Server Express and the Bamboo version 5.11.3, I am testing upgrading from 5.11.3 to 5.15 with larges amounts of data which is why I am using that version.

Error from Bamboo is:
Error accessing database: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'Bamboo'.

Error from SQL logs is:
Login failed for user 'Bamboo' Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Bamboo en SQLExpress on the same machine? If not, you should look into the [remote access configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191464.aspx).

In the SQL Sever Configuration Manager, make sure that you entered 1433 for the IPAll entry as well. And start the SQL Browser service for good measure, this is especially important when using a names instance, but going after the errorlog folder you copy/pasted, that's not the case.

For testing purposes, you might want to disable the firewall all together and reactivate is after you get the connection up.

Another thing to try if you're connecting on the same machine, is use the loopback address 127.0.0.1 instead of the localhost alias.

Comment: Yes its the same machine, the IPAll is set to 1433, the firewall is now disabled same result

Comment: Can you add the actual error message(s) to your initial post please?

Comment: @CiaranDonoghue  any luck with this? I'm having similar issue. Frustrating even with supports guidance